# How to remove the surround IIFE from @babel/template?

Tags: babeljs, babel-plugin

I'm trying to convert some Ember codes to React. Here is what I want to transform.

*From*

```js
export default Ember.Component.extend(({
    didInsertElement() { }
});
```

*To*

```js
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() { }
}
```

I write a babel plugin, and try to replace the `Ember.Component.extend` call with an AST node which is produced by `template` method. Here is the code snippet.

*babel-plugin*

```js
const { default: template } = require("@babel/template");

const code = `class TestComponent extends React.Component { 
   componentDidMount() { }
 }`;
let classDeclarationNode = template.ast(code);
module.exports = function ({ types: t }) {
    return {
        visitor: {
            CallExpression(path) {
                if (!path.getSource().startsWith("Ember.Component.extend")) {
                    return;
                }
                path.replaceWith(classDeclarationNode);
            }
        }
    };
};
```

*Output*

```js
export default (function () {
  class TestComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {}
  }
})();
```

Instead of the expected code I wrote above, I get the `ClassDeclaration` statement surrounded with `IIFE`. Is there any way to remove the `IIFE`?

I have struggled with the problem one whole day, but have no way to resolve it.

---

BTW, I also tried `parseExpression` method, but still can't get what exactly I want.

*babel-plugin*

```js
const { parseExpression } = require('@babel/parser');

const code = `class TestComponent extends React.Component { 
    componentDidMount() { }
}`;
let expression = parseExpression(code);
module.exports = function ({ types: t }) {
    return {
        visitor: {
            CallExpression(path) {
                if (!path.getSource().startsWith("Ember.Component.extend")) {
                    return;
                }
                path.replaceWith(expression);
            }
        }
    };
};
```

*Output*

```js
export default (class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {}
});
```

It's quite close to the correct code, except an extra pair of `()`. Is there any way to generate the pure `class declaration`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help of `loganfsmyth` on Slack, the problem was finally resolved. I should replace the node of whole `export default` but not only the `CallExpression`. Here is the code.

*babel-plugin*

```js
const { default: template } = require("@babel/template");

const code = `export default class TestComponent extends React.Component { 
   componentDidMount() { }
 }`;
let rootNode = template.ast(code);
module.exports = function ({ types: t }) {
    return {
        visitor: {
            ExportDefaultDeclaration(path) {
                let isMatchedNode = (path.node.declaration &&
                    t.matchesPattern(path.node.declaration.callee, "Ember.Component.extend"));
                if (!isMatchedNode) {
                    return;
                }
                path.replaceWith(rootNode);
            }
        }
    };
};
```

*Output*

```js
export default class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {}
}
```